# Avoid collision - Corona

Tags: lua, sprite, coronasdk, collision

I have initialized the object named jet to collide when it interacts with other objects, But when i move the jet and touch the ceiling or floor they are also exploding. How to avoid getting collision function with ceiling & Floor? Here is the code.

Ceiling Object

```
ceiling = display.newImage("invisibleTile.png")
ceiling:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
ceiling.x = 0
ceiling.y = 0
physics.addBody(ceiling, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2})
screenGroup:insert(ceiling)
local groundShape = { -280,-20, 280,-20, 280,20, -280,20 }
```

Floor Object

```
theFloor = display.newImage("invisibleTile.png")
theFloor:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
theFloor.x = 0
theFloor.y = 300
physics.addBody(theFloor, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, shape=groundShape })
screenGroup:insert(theFloor)
```

**Jet Object**

```
jetSpriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("greenman.png", 128, 128)
jetSprites = sprite.newSpriteSet(jetSpriteSheet, 1, 4)
sprite.add(jetSprites, "jets", 1, 15, 500, 0)
jet = sprite.newSprite(jetSprites)
jet.x = 180
jet.y = 280
jet:prepare("jets")
jet:play()
**jet.collided = false**
physics.addBody(jet, {density=0.1, bounce=0.5, friction=1, radius=12})
```

explosive method

```
function explode()
explosion.x = jet.x
explosion.y = jet.y
explosion.isVisible = true
explosion:play()
jet.isVisible = false
timer.performWithDelay(3000, gameOver, 1)
end
```

Collision method

```
function onCollision(event)
if event.phase == "began" then
  if jet.collided == false then 
    jet.collided = true
    jet.bodyType = "static"
    explode()
    storyboard.gotoScene("restart", "fade", 400)
  end
end
end
```

Where exactly need to specify the condition to avoid colloids objects ?please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, if you want to not detect collisions all by themselves, you should [filter collisions.](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/) [This link.](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/2128-collision-filters-helper-chart/) contains a helpful table and tutorial to help you determine the maskbits and categorybits. Another alternative is group indexing, which you can read more [on the first link.](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/) at the end of the document.

But, from what i see on your code, your ceiling and floor might be exploding as well. is happening is that your collision function `onCollision` is treating all objects the same. You would need to assign a name to your jet object `jet.name = "jet"`, then, on your collision function check if the object really is the jet:

```
function onCollision(event)
    if event.phase == "began" and "jet" == event.object1.name then
        if jet.collided == false then 
            jet.collided = true
            jet.bodyType = "static"
            explode()
            storyboard.gotoScene("restart", "fade", 400)
        end
    end
end
```

Note that you should also assign a name to all other physics objects, in case you would like to do something special with each body, and don't forget to reset `jet.collided` once you restart your game, if it implements it.

Read more about collision detection [on the Corona Docs.](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/)